# How can I borrow an index return by .iter().enumerate with longer lifetime in rust

Tags: rust, lifetime

Suppose I have a grid that contains a Vec<Vec>, and I want a function that returns an iterator that contains both the position and the value, like (0,0,100),(0,1,200), ...

So I wrote following code:

```
pub struct Grid<T>
where
    T: Clone,
{
    values: Vec<Vec<T>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct GridItem<T>
where
    T: Clone,
{
    pub val: T,
    pub x: usize,
    pub y: usize,
}

impl<T> Grid<T>
where
    T: Clone,
{
    pub fn get_items<'a>(&'a self) -> impl Iterator<Item = GridItem<T>> + 'a {
        let mut it: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = GridItem<T>> + 'a> = Box::new(std::iter::empty());
        for (i, l) in self.values.iter().enumerate() {
            let ii = l
                .iter()
                .enumerate()
                .map(|(j, x)| GridItem {
                    val: x.clone(),
                    x: j,
                    y: i, // y: 0 compiles
                })
                .into_iter();
            it = Box::new(it.chain(ii));
        }
        it
    }
}
```

and got following error:

```
error[E0597]: `i` does not live long enough
  --> src/grid.rs:51:24
   |
42 |     pub fn get_items<'a>(&'a self) -> impl Iterator<Item = GridItem<T>> + 'a {
   |                      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
43 |         let mut it: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = GridItem<T>> + 'a> = Box::new(std::iter::empty());
   |                     ------------------------------------------ type annotation requires that `i` is borrowed for `'a`
...
48 |                 .map(|(j, x)| GridItem {
   |                      -------- value captured here
...
51 |                     y: i,
   |                        ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
55 |         }
   |         - `i` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I have understand the compiler error, but I have no idea how to fix it. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the closure `|(j, x)| GridItem ...` only holds a *reference* to `i` which will drop out of scope before the closure will be called. You can fix this by *moving* `i` into the closure:

```
.map(move |(j, x)| GridItem { ...
  // ^^^^
```

---

Rather than iteratively building the iterator via `.chain`, consider using [`.flat_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map):

```
pub fn get_items<'a>(&'a self) -> impl Iterator<Item = GridItem<T>> + 'a {
    self.values.iter().enumerate().flat_map(|(i, vec)| {
        vec.iter().enumerate().map(move |(j, val)| GridItem {
            val: val.clone(),
            x: j,
            y: i,
        })
    })
}
```